# Expression type vs. expression value category vs. object type and when is which used?

Tags: c++, types, expression

There are three somewhat different concepts in c++:

Value category of an expression

- lvalue, rvalue, etc.
- I'm not able to formalize this, but roughly said, it's something that can often be relatively easy to deduce in a purely grammatical way. For example with "1.0" or "n" you often don't need any sort of knowledge of the context - you simply look at the actual symbols of the expression and can deduce the expression.
- There are exceptions to this however - with `f(x)` for example we need to know whether `f` is a function or a type, and we also need to know whether it returns a value/reference type.

Type of an expression

- An intuitive explanation of this would be "if this expression were to be evaluated, it would have some value. What would be the type of this value ?". Because it has to do with values, there can not be any sort of reference type - the type of an expression is a non reference type.
- Unlike the above, this can easily require some sort of knowledge of the context - to deduce the type of "n" you need a symbol table that stores the type of "n".

Type of an object

- This seems a bit more complicated, as an object is something that really only exists in the abstract, at runtime. While it's not something directly understandable as something in source code, regardless of the philosophical difference, we can say that whatever the object is, the type of the object is induced by a declaration expression
- e.g. for `int& x` the object that the identifier `x` is associated with, is of type `int&`

//

**1,** Are the descriptions above correct in the sense that they at least roughly match how these concepts are described in the standard?

**2,** Assuming they are, how and in what situations are these properties used?

As an example, to resolve overloading, it seems to me that only the expression properties can be used  for example - the relevant property of whether the object type is a reference or not is encapsulated in the expression value category to some extent, so we don't strictly need to know whether the return object is an lvalue reference type or not - the case when it is, is already contained in the definition of lvalue.

What are some examples of when the object type itself is used, rather than just the expression type?

I am mostly interested in this from the perspective of the standard, but a description on how it might differ from the compiler point of view will be also appreciated.

Comment: The question is too broad for a SO post and not clear enough, IMO. You should refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Also, [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues).

Comment: Also are you asking the question from C++ standards' perspective or compiler's perspective. This is the main point you should add in your question.

Comment: One clarification, references are not objects. So *"`int& x` the object that the identifier `x` is associated with, is of type `int&`"* is not correct. `x` is a reference referring to an object of type `int`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah yes, I should have used the term "entity" that would be general enough, correct?

Comment: @JasonLiam I've attempted to clarify the question by removing the parts I found confusing and specifying what sort of answer I'm looking for a bit more, let me know if you think this is clearer and thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jake1234 You can use "entity", which includes just about everything. You can also use "variable", which is either an object or reference introduced by a declaration.

Comment: It's complicated. There's a reason the standard is 1300+ pages long.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Very well, I'll delete the question and attempt to pose a more concrete one in the future. At the least, are the three terms I mentioned described in a somewhat reasonably matching what the standard specifies, or is my understanding of those concepts completely off, and they are something completely different?

Comment: *"whatever the object is, the type of the object is induced by a declaration expression"* Not all objects have declarations. E.g. in `A *ptr = new B;`, the instance of `B` has none.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for the correction. It would be more correct tho say "the type of the object is bound at the time the object is created, and it is induced the type that is used the expression that creates it", do you think that is general enough?

Comment: *"and it is induced the type"* My sleepy brain can't parse this, sorry. :P The first half sounds correct. This is also called the [*dynamic type*](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.dynamic.type#def:type,dynamic) of an expression.

Comment: Should have been "... and it is induced by the type that is used in the expression ...". It's vague enough that it probably a bit hard for it to be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Value category of an expression

> Type of an expression

Both of these require knowing not only the grammar of the expression used, which itself requires knowing whether names are types/templates (C++'s cannot be parsed without doing name lookup and understanding declarations), but also require knowing the value category and types of the operands of the expression. That's not only true for postfix expressions. It also applies e.g. to member access.

---

> Type of an object

This is independent of the types and value categories of expressions as you said. All compile-time properties, such as overload resolution, are determined completely by value category and type of expressions. The *result* of an expression when evaluated (at runtime) may refer to some object (if it is a glvalue expression). The type of this object is not necessarily the same as the type of the expression and can vary between multiple evaluations of the same expression.

Usually the result of a glvalue expression of a given type is supposed to refer to an object of the same (up to qualifiers) type, but that is not generally guaranteed. Similarly a pointer value of a give pointed-to-type should be a pointer to an object of that same type (up to qualifiers), but that is not guaranteed. Basically the only way to violate these is however to use potentially dangerous casts such as `reinterpret_cast`.

A declaration `int& x = /*...*/;` doesn't declare or create any object. A reference is not considered an object. `x` will refer to the object which is the result of the right-hand side. As above, it may not necessarily have the type `int`. For example:

```
alignas(int) char y;
int& x = reinterpret_cast<int&>(y);
```

now the name `x` used in an expression has type `int` and value category lvalue, but the result of the lvalue expression refers to an object of type `char` (and access through this lvalue is not allowed because it would be an aliasing violation).

---

Objects are also not only created by declarations. As you said they are a runtime property that can only be talked about when considering a particular state of program execution. Other than from (non-reference) variables, objects can for example be created explicitly as temporary objects (via temporary materialization conversion from prvalues to xvalues), by `new` expressions or implicitly by certain operations which are defined to do so (e.g. a call to `std::malloc` under certain (strict) conditions).

It is also possible to reuse storage of objects, even from declared variables, or to nest objects in certain other objects. For example

```
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int));

alignas(float) int x;
new(&x) float;
```

Now if the assertion succeeds after the `new` expression the `int` object from the declaration is not alive anymore and trying to read/write through `x` with

```
x = 1;
```

would have undefined behavior as `x` refers to an object outside its lifetime, but e.g.

```
*std::launder(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&x)) = 1;
```

will be fine after the `new` expression (but not before), because `reinterpret_cast<float*>(&x)` is a prvalue expression of type `float*` with a pointer value pointing to the out-of-lifetime `int` object, while the additional `std::launder` call adjusts the pointer value to point to the `float` object at the same storage location which is inside its lifetime.

(However you generally have to make sure that once the lifetime of the declared object would end normally, e.g. at the end of its scope, that there actually is an object of the correct type alive (and *transparently-replacable* with the original object) at the storage location. Otherwise you will have undefined behavior. Also, there is usually no practical reason for an example as above. One can simply declare two variables instead and have the compiler figure out whether the same storage can be reused.)

---

There is also the related concept of *dynamic type* of an expression, which however is slightly different from all of the above. Consider for example

```
struct A {
    virtual int f() { return 1; } 
};
struct B : A {
    int f() override { return 2; } 
};

B b;
A& a = b;
int x = a.f();
```

Here `a` in the last expression is an lvalue of type `A` and the result of the expression also refers to an object of type `A`, specifically the `A` base subobject of `b`, but the *dynamic type* of the expression for this specific evaluation is `B`, the *most-derived type* of the object to which the result of the expression `a` refers. This concept is used to determine which function override should be called in virtual dispatch but does not affect the (static) type or value category of the call expression `a.f()`. Using `A& a = reinterpret_cast<A&>(b);` instead would change the type of the result of the expression `a` to `B` and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: "The result of an expression when evaluated (at runtime) may refer to some object (if it is a glvalue expression)." - could you please clarify what exactly you mean by "result" of an expression? Would it be appropriate to think it of it as some runtime entity, i.e. an actual object, or say a reference to an object, that the expression corresponds to? Would it be perhaps be correct to say that for `int& x = ...` the result of `x`, in the way that you use it, is an entity of type `int&` ?

Comment: @Jake1234 The result of an expression is what you get when you evaluate the expression. "_The result of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression._" (https://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#5.sentence-1). The entity here is either an object or a function. It is not a reference. (https://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1.1) The result of `x` is whatever object the reference is bound to, not the reference itself. (https://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1)

Comment: @Jake1234 Although I have to admit that this may not be entirely correct. I am not fully sure what precise meaning "_result_" is supposed to have. It is true that e.g. the id-expression `x` _denotes_ (per lookup rules) the reference itself and the definition of _result_ in the standard says that it is the entity _denoted_ by it. However that doesn't seem to make sense for other kinds of glvalue expressions. So my use of "result" may not be completely in line with the standard. I intent it to mean the result of the evaluation after type adjustment per expr.type/1.

Comment: @Jake1234 See for example discussion in https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/44.

Comment: Based on your note "All compile-time properties, such as overload resolution, are determined completely by value category and type of expressions. ", is it not a bit redundant to even have the concept of "reference type"? Instead of `x` variable in `int& x` being considered of type `int&`, it seems that it would be enough to say that `x` is of type `int` and is "reference" initialized. Functions would return/pass by reference.

Is the concept of a reference type at least actually used anywhere by the standard? E.g. are there perhaps some rules of type "If `x` is a reference type, then..."?

Comment: @Jake1234 Reference types can syntactically be used pretty much everywhere that non-reference types can be used. There are also constructs which use the type of the _entity_ denoted by a name directly instead of the result of the corresponding expression. For example `decltype(x)` is `int&`, not `int`. It is only in expressions that the reference types are replaced by value category, but the two are not synonymous, e.g. `int&& y = /*...*/;` when used as `y` in an expression is a lvalue, the same as `x`, but the type of the entity denoted by `y` is `int&&`.

Comment: You can find rules of the kind you are looking for by simply searching for "reference type" in the standard. See e.g. in the draft [expr] section [here](https://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr). They are very common but at the same time many rules apply to reference types as they do to non-reference types.

Comment: I see - yes it is very frequently used as an auxiliary element for other rules in some sense. I suppose it's the choice to couple the concept of reference to the concept of a type, rather than "referencing" describing way of doing things, that seems a bit weird to me. Subjectively, it doesn't seem like it's fitting to consider it an inherent feature of an entity/variable - which a "reference type" implies to me. But that's very subjective and pedantic, as it could also be said that "being of type T" is equivalent to "behaves/was acquired in a way W".

Comment: It might also simply be easier to reason about rules, code etc. when all its properties of a variable are in one place - the "type". `decltype` seems like a great example as it uses the reference property directly and highlights a possible neat feature that's possible when "reference" is thought of as an inherent part of the type. Thank you for your answer and your further comments.